# Python webscraping can't pull data from table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Can someone please explain me how I am able to scrape data from this website
https://www.ngm.se/marknaden/vardepapper?symbol=ETH%20ZERO%20SEK

I try to scrape this part [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv9bq.png)

This is how my code looks:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
   
URL = "https://www.ngm.se/marknaden/vardepapper?symbol=ETH%20ZERO%20SEK"
r = requests.get(URL)
   
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
   
gdp_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "GGT05EYCJ"})
gdp_table_data = gdp_table.tbody.find_all("tr")

headings = []
for td in gdp_table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())
    
print(headings)
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: when you request the page you are not getting the table because the page is loaded dynamically (if you turn off javascript on your browser is what you get in a request object). Therefore another way to get the same information is to use something like selenium, which will allow you to simulate the browser. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: If you use the inspect feature in your browser you can see that the page is pulling JSON data at regular intervals, and it seems you'll have to perform a POST request with certain parameters. But this would be an easier approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract the table from the given URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71033791/how-can-i-extract-the-table-from-the-given-url)