# How can I extract the table from the given URL

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data from the table ETH ZERO SEK of the given URL, however I can't make it work. Does anyone have some advise how I can get it to work?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.ngm.se/marknaden/vardepapper?symbol=ETH%20ZERO%20SEK'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element(By.Xpath, './/*[@id="detailviewDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

Content you are looking for is provided via `iframe`, so you `xpath` won't work.

#### How to fix?

**Option#1**

Change your url to `https://mdweb.ngm.se/detailview.html?locale=sv_SE&symbol=ETH%20ZERO%20SEK` and call content directly

**Option#2**

Grab the source of iframe from your original url:

```
driver.get('https://www.ngm.se/marknaden/vardepapper?symbol=ETH%20ZERO%20SEK')
```

get the src of iframe that holds your table

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe').get_attribute("src")
```

get the iframe

```
driver.get(iframe)
```

wait until your tbody of table is located and store it in element

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="detailviewDiv"]//thead[.//span[contains(text(),"Volym")]]/following-sibling::tbody')))
```

Assign values from cells to variables, by split of elements text:

```
volym = element.text.split('\n')[-3]
vwap = element.text.split('\n')[-2]
```

**Note** *waits requires - `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`*

Comment: This gives me the following output:
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0da540ed02a2e39ce5f1a7b955defa81", element="52df6389-6fe3-4491-a136-9d0f23e698a1")>

But how do I print the data of the table?

Comment: There is no expected output defined in your question, so it is hard to give a specific answer - One simple option is `element.text` else you have to improve your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input and excuse me being unspecific. I'm still new in the developing scene. The desired output is the "Volym" and the "VWAP" value from the first table on the website. Currently these values are 216664 for Volym and 28,364 for VWAP. Can you help me understand how what needs to be done to scrape this values from the website?

Comment: Edited the last two snippets, so that you will get the values from volym and vwap.